# Cognito - Reset password check previous password

Tags: compare, amazon-cognito, reset-password, aws-userpools

I have the authentication management in my app with Cognito.

There I have a reset password windows to be able to reset the password of a user.

I can reset the password, however, I would like to check if the current password is the same as the new one from the "New Password" box.

Is there any parameter or any way to compare the new password with the current one in a user?

Comment: not sure, if it is there, but you could use a workaround? get id token of current user, extract user email, use "current password" field to sign in, and if successful, compare to new password...

Comment: Unfortunately Cognito does not provide a way to block previously used passwords, or compare historic password.